# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when adding object to array

Tags: c++, class

I am new programming and C++. I am trying to create a `Roster` of `Person` objects using an array and then printing the attributes of the People in the `Roster`.

When I attempt to add a Person to the `personArray`, I am getting an

```
Exception = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0).
```

I think this has to do with the scope of my `personArray` but I can't seem to figure it out.

Here is the code I am using:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Person 
{
public:
    Person(string name, int age);
    string getName() {
        return name;
    }
    void setName(string n) {
        name = n;
    }
    int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    void setAge(int a) {
        age = a;
    }
private:
    string name;
    int age;
};

class Roster {
public:
    void addToPersonArray(string name, string age) {
        Person person(name, stoi(age));
        personArray[personCount] = &person;
    }
    void printPersonArray() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            cout << personArray[i]->getName() << '\t' << personArray[i]->getAge() << '\n';
    }
private:
    Person *personArray[5];
    int personCount = 0;
};

int main() {
    const string studentData[] = {"Dan,45", "Mark,33", "Mary,22", 
"April,17", "Jill,22"};
    Roster roster;

    stringstream ss(studentData[0]); // just testing the first entry
    vector<string> result;

    while (ss.good()) {
        string substr;
        getline(ss, substr, ',');
        result.push_back(substr);
    }
    roster.printPersonArray();
}
```

Comment: is there any special reason that you do not want `std::vector<Person> personArray`?

Comment: I am being tasked with using an array specifically. Vector is generally preferred because the size being dynamically adjusted, correct?

Comment: Yes. But here the size seems to be fixed. Then you can use [`std::vector::reserve`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) to reserve the size of your array(probably in the constructor of  `Roster`) and no re allocation will occur. Or simply use `std::array` with a fixed size.

Comment: @MarkScheer First, there is no "Person" array anywhere in your code.  You have an array of pointers to Persons.  If you really did have a Person array, then it is a simple matter of creating a Person and assigning it to one of the array elements, no different than if you had an `int` array and want to assing an `int` to one of the array entries.

Comment: *Vector is generally preferred because the size being dynamically adjusted, correct?* -- Your `printPersonArray` accesses uninitialized pointers, since your loop just assumes there are 5 valid entries.  If there is any reason for `vector`, that alone is one of them, regardless if `vector` is dynamic or not.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - Thank you for the clarification. I am tasked with using the array of pointers to Person objects. I was not clear before.

Comment: This is why you shouldn't store pointers in containers. Almost every time I've seen it done, it's been done wrong. And if you want to do it, you are probably wrong. Exceptions to this rule include (but are not limited to) building "indexes" of things, but even then a std::weak_ptr will be appropriate and not be prone to scope mistakes like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
void addToPersonArray(string name, string age) {
    Person person(name, stoi(age));
    personArray[personCount] = &person;
}
```

`person` is a local variable in the member function `addToPersonArray()`, which will be destroyed after the function scope.

Hence, storing the address of a local variable(and trying to accessing it latter in `printPersonArray()`)  will give you, nothing but an [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

You are lucky that your programme got the exception.

---

One more thing to note that, you are not actually using your `roster` to test the program. Instead, all you do is parsing and saving to `result` vector. You can add this after the `while` loop, to make it actually work.

```
if (result.size() == 2) {
     roster.addToPersonArray(result[0], result[1]);
}
```

---

**Suggestion**: Since you have a fixed array size, you probably wanna do it with `std::array<Person, 5>` or with `std::vector<Person>` by [reserving the memory](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) for 5 `Person` in the c'tor of `Roster`.

See a sample output: https://wandbox.org/permlink/tAGqqnhCfwz1wPrH

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

class Person {
public:
    Person(const std::string& name, int age): name(name), age(age) {}
    std::string getName()const { return name;   }
    void setName(const std::string& n){ name = n;   }
    int getAge()const     { return age;     }
    void setAge(int a)    { age = a;    }
private:
    std::string name;
    int age;
};

class Roster {
public:
    Roster() { personArray.reserve(5); } // reserve some memory
    void addToPersonArray(const std::string& name, const std::string& age) {
        personArray.emplace_back(name, stoi(age));
    }
    void printPersonArray() {
        // use range loop, which will assure, access what you have.
        for (const Person& person: personArray)
            std::cout << person.getName() << '\t' << person.getAge() << '\n';
    }
private:
    std::vector<Person> personArray;
    //int personCount = 0; --------------> no need anymore
};

int main() {
    std::array<std::string,5> studentData{ "Dan,45", "Mark,33", "Mary,22", "April,17", "Jill,22" };
    Roster roster;
    for(const std::string& str: studentData)
    {
        std::stringstream ss(str);
        std::vector<std::string> result;    
        while (ss.good()) {
            std::string substr;
            std::getline(ss, substr, ',');
            result.emplace_back(substr);
        }
        if (result.size() == 2) {
            roster.addToPersonArray(result
                [0], result[1]);
        }
    }
    roster.printPersonArray();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Dan     45
Mark    33
Mary    22
April   17
Jill    22
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to storing pointers to local variables in your `addToPersonArray()` function, your `main()` function does not add any entries to the `personArray`.

Instead, `main` creates a `Roster` object, and after some code that doesn't affect anything with `Roster`, you go straight into calling `roster.printPersonArray`, which does this:

```
void printPersonArray() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)  // <-- This will loop for all 5 entries
        cout << personArray[i]->getName() << '\t' << personArray[i]->getAge() << '\n';
}
```

Since `personArray` was never initialized to contain valid pointers to `Person` objects, that loop will cause undefined behavior.

The issue is that you have a `personCount` member variable, but fail to make use of it to control how many valid entries there are in the array.  The loop should have been written as below:

```
void printPersonArray() 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < personCount; i++)  
        cout << personArray[i]->getName() << '\t' << personArray[i]->getAge() << '\n';
}
```

In addition to the storage of pointers to local variables, your `Roster::addToPersonArray()` doesn't check if `personCount` is greater than 4, thus this is another place in your code where you failed to use `personCount` to control how many `Person` objects are being referenced.